# Assist with currency format

Tags: sql, oracle, format, currency

Good Day please can someone assist me with a currency format of ###,###,###.## everything I try I seem to be getting stuck - My code is as follows:

`function CF_TOTAL_COSTFormula return Number is
total_cost number;
begin
  select SUM(share_amount) into total_cost
  from reservation_name rn,
         reservation_daily_element_name rden
  where rn.resv_name_id = rden.resv_name_id
  and rn.resv_name_id = :resv_name_id
  and trunc(rden.reservation_date) between trunc(rn.begin_date) and trunc(rn.end_date - 1);
  return total_cost;
exception when others then
    return 0;
end;`

Comment: The above code kicks out a figure such as 1234, I want it to be in the format 1,234.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a `NUMBER`.  Numbers in Oracle have no format.  If you want to return a formatted number, you need to return a `VARCHAR2`.  Something like this:

```
function CF_TOTAL_COSTFormula return varchar2 is
total_cost varchar2(30);
begin
  select to_char(SUM(share_amount),'999,999,990.00') into total_cost
  from reservation_name rn,
         reservation_daily_element_name rden
  where rn.resv_name_id = rden.resv_name_id
  and rn.resv_name_id = :resv_name_id
  and trunc(rden.reservation_date) between trunc(rn.begin_date) and trunc(rn.end_date - 1);
  return total_cost;
exception when others then
    return 'error';
end;
```

As an aside, I gather from the name of your function that perhaps you are using Oracle Reports or Oracle BI Publisher.  If so, you should continue to return a number and handle the display formatting in the layout, not the model.

Comment: This has worked like a charm, I have applied it to multiple fields I was struggling with and it is perfect! I am using Oracle Reports you are 100% correct but what I am using them for is very difficult to customize the format in the front end as it affects other layouts. Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: I do have one more issue maybe you can advise on, I have a calculation which is currently spitting out 4 decimals but I want to round to the nearest 2 decimals, I have tried using the ROUND((ret_val),2) but it is rounding to the nearest rand no matter if I increase the 2 to a 6 even, any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure what "rounding to the nearest rand" means.  But, `ROUND(x,2)` will round `x` to two decimal places.  Keep in mind, that, again, numbers have no format.  So, `round(3.4976)` will be 3.5, not "3.50".